# Lua - Insert table values

Tags: lua, lua-table

I got a table of form let's say:

```
house = {
             ["Street 22"] = {
                        {name = "George", age = 20},
                        {name = "Pete", age = 25}
                      },
             ["Street 30"] = {
                        {name = "John", age = 32},
                    }
           }
```

And I want to insert programmatically a third house, that is key "Street 35", with a person's details, Nick and 30 let's say. I am relatively new to lua and don't know how to do this, I must use `table.insert` but I am having troubles following the above format... Some help please?

Comment: `house["Street 35"] = house["Street 35"] or {}; table.insert(house["Street 35"], {name = "Nick", age = 30})`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do it simple so:

```
house["Street 52"] = {{name = "Nick", age = 30}}
```

Answer (score 3):

did you read [this](https://www.lua.org/pil/19.2.html) and get confused?

just try `table.insert(house, {name = "Nick", age = 30})` and `house[3]` now contains the new element.

Comment: Thanks, that works, it was simple indeed. But I edited my question a bit, what if I need to add a key "Street 52" for example with name and age the ones I mention...?

Answer (score 3):

You could also mutate the third element of the houses table like this:

```
house[3]={name = "Nick", age = 30}
```